# Need help with "removing" normals

Tags: normals

**I was able to figure out how to achieve the normal effect, all I had to do is point the normals up on the Z axis with Align turned on.**

Recently I saw a model which has a very weird set of Normal data and I have no clue how to replicate it.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Please be so kind and try to formulate your question differently. As I understand it at the moment, it makes me smile: "I want the cube to look like the cat" ;-) ...that sounds like "I want the banana to look like a gorilla". Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome. If that's a render (not sure because i can't see your GUI) then you can achieve that with an Emission shader

Comment: @Emir it's in viewport shading

Comment: Do you mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTmCn.png. Or you mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FH13.png

Comment: Close but not exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have recorded a gif of how I want it to behave. https://gyazo.com/e0a6d4260cda14377f70371e0adeaf10

Comment: So, i dont know ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This looks more like a comment and a question to the user than an answer

Comment: You should add more details to your question, the more, the better. Like what kind of light does your viewport shading is using? does it has any type of material? add more images if you need to or GIF too.

Comment: Everything's default, it has nothing to do with lighting, it's all in the normals.

Comment: @DamirAlkhaov But your GIF is moving, the images ugorek posted are stationary. If you take the setup from his first image and move around in the viewport, the shading changes as well.

Comment: Hi @DamirAlkhaov.. you seem to have found a satisfactory solution. Would you be so kind as to post it as an answer to your own question with a brief explanation of how you did it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

[image: demo]

Or you mean this?

[image]

Comment: Close but not exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have recorded a gif of how I want it to behave. https://gyazo.com/e0a6d4260cda14377f70371e0adeaf10

Comment: So, i dont know ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This looks more like a comment and a question to the user than an answer

Comment: @DamirAlkhaov Actually I would accept this answer as solution, since the first setup works exactly like your GIF (only that there's no kitten model in it). I don't know why you say it's not what you want, maybe you could point out where it differs from your desired result which might be not visible in your example.